# how to hide an element in xamarin forms webview

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview

I have a website and now want to make iOS/Android APP to show content of my website. I plan to use Xamarin.Forms and WebView. The problem is, APP doesn't need to show as much as website, so I want to hide some elements of webpages. For example, there is an element whose id is "test", I want to use EvaluateJavaScriptAsync to hide it.

Comment: What is your question?  Do you know how to use javascript to toggle the visibility of an element?  Do you know how to use `EvaluateJavaScriptAsync` to execute that script on your page?  What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.